# Observable ConcurrentModification Exception

Tags: java, observable

I got a problem with the observer design pattern.

I tried to implement something like Observers on my own and ran into a nasty error I don't understand.

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(Unknown Source)
at userInterface.PauseScreen.acknowledgeChanges(PauseScreen.java:57)
at userInterface.PauseScreen$1.getPressed(PauseScreen.java:22)
at evo.EvoMain.update(EvoMain.java:76)
at org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer.updateAndRender(GameContainer.java:646)
at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.gameLoop(AppGameContainer.java:412)
at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.start(AppGameContainer.java:322)
at evo.EvoMain.main(EvoMain.java:32)
Sat May 26 17:28:31 CEST 2018 ERROR:Game.update() failure - check the game code.
org.newdawn.slick.SlickException: Game.update() failure - check the game code.
at org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer.updateAndRender(GameContainer.java:663)
at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.gameLoop(AppGameContainer.java:412)
at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.start(AppGameContainer.java:322)
at evo.EvoMain.main(EvoMain.java:32)
```

Background: I'm programming a game in java in Slick2D and it's going kind of in the direction of Diablo. When I heard about the observer design pattern I got excited and tried to implement it into my game, so the different components can easily communicate with each other.
I would like the Pause screen to communicate to the game's Main class.
I'd also like the Main class to be communicating with the player's status screen.
These two communication paths are mainly to tell those components what input was made and to get the button they got pressed as feedback. I would also like the statscreen to be communicating with the player. 1st: I want the stat screen to tell the player which stat he is supposed to upgrade and 2nd: I want the player to return his stats (hp, hpRegeneration, stamina, staminaRegen, dmg) to the stat screen so the user can look at them there and read the numbers. I guess this could be implemented without Observers, but I had difficulties and thought it would be better in the long run to implement observers and keep the objects independent that way.

So to show you some pictures:

[Start up screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmMpq.jpg)

At this point the user presses Start and the game initializes.
The monsters and the player are loaded and everything else.

Unfortunately the "Start"-Button produces a wierd ConcurrentModificationError when it tries to tell the game that it was pressed. What's even more wierd to me, is the fact that the error only occurs, if I add the player to his/her statScreen as a listener which makes no sense to me, it seems so unrelated.

[The line which causes the error to come up. If I deactivate the line, the game works perfectly.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wP4t.png)

Edit: Sometimes when I put a breakpoint on the line of code where the error happens, the line gets triggered 3 times before the Exception comes up. On the first 2 breaks the observers ArrayList contains the EvoMain, on the third run however, it also contains the player. Why is that?
[Player is one of PauseScreen's Observers why?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GofLs.jpg)
When I remove the line of code mentioned further above
[The line which causes the error to come up. If I deactivate the line, the game works perfectly.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wP4t.png)
The player does not appear in the ArrayList and the game starts normally.
Could it be that some kind of error is causing that ArrayList to be shared between the objects pauseScreen and statScreen? It seems to be static?! 
End-edit.

I removed most of the actual game content from this version of the game in order to isolate the faulty code.
Here are my classes:

EvoMain:

```
package evo;

import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Map;
import org.lwjgl.input.Mouse;
import org.newdawn.slick.*;
import userInterface.EPauseScreenMessage;
import userInterface.PauseScreen;
import userInterface.StatScreen;

public class EvoMain extends BasicGame implements Observer {

private static Map<String, Image> imageCatalogue = new Hashtable<String, Image>();
private static Player player = null;
private static PauseScreen pauseScreen = null;
private static StatScreen statScreen = null;
private static GameContainer container;

private static int state = 0;   // 0 = paused, 1 = running

public EvoMain() throws SlickException {
    super("Evo");
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws SlickException {
    AppGameContainer container = new AppGameContainer(new EvoMain());
    container.setDisplayMode(1200, 900, false);
    container.start();
}

@Override
public void render(GameContainer container, Graphics g) throws SlickException {
    if (player != null) {
        player.render(container, g);
        statScreen.render(container, g);
    }
    pauseScreen.render(container, g);
}

@Override
public void init(final GameContainer container) throws SlickException {
    fillImageCatalogue();
    EvoMain.container = container;
    pauseScreen = new PauseScreen(200, 100);
    pauseScreen.add(this);
    pauseScreen.setVisible(true);
    pauseScreen.setEnabled(true);
    statScreen = new StatScreen(0, 0, imageCatalogue.get("PlusButton"));
    statScreen.add(this);
    container.setMinimumLogicUpdateInterval(55);
    container.setMaximumLogicUpdateInterval(55);
}

@Override
public void update(GameContainer container, int delta) throws SlickException {
    Input input = container.getInput();
    switch (state) {
    case 0:
        if(input.isKeyPressed(Input.KEY_ESCAPE)){
            resumeGame();
            break;
        }
        if (input.isKeyPressed(Input.KEY_ENTER)) {
            resumeGame();
            break;
        }
        if (input.isMouseButtonDown(0)) {
            if (pauseScreen.isVisible() && pauseScreen.isEnabled()) {
                for (Button button : pauseScreen.getButtons()) {
                    if (button.getRect().contains(Mouse.getX(), container.getHeight() - Mouse.getY())) {
                        // for some weird reason Mouse.getY() always gives the container height - the mouse' y coord so I have to reverse that by doing the same
                        button.getPressed();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        break;  // end of pause state
    case 1:
        if(input.isKeyPressed(Input.KEY_ESCAPE)){
            state = 0;
            pauseScreen.setVisible(true);
            pauseScreen.setEnabled(true);
            break;
        }
        if(input.isKeyPressed(Input.KEY_T)){
            if (statScreen.isEnabled()) {
                statScreen.setEnabled(false);
                statScreen.setVisible(false);
            } else {
                statScreen.setVisible(true);
                statScreen.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }
        int dX = -1; // player destination X
        int dY = -1; // player destination Y
        if (input.isMouseButtonDown(0)) {
            dX = Mouse.getX();
            dY = container.getHeight() - Mouse.getY();
            if (statScreen.isVisible() && statScreen.isEnabled()) {
                for (Button button : statScreen.getButtons()) {
                    if (button.getRect().contains(dX, dY)) {
                        button.getPressed();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (player != null) {
            player.setDestination(dX, dY);
        }
        break; // end of running state
    }
}
public void resumeGame() {
    state = 1;
    pauseScreen.setVisible(false);
    pauseScreen.setEnabled(false);
}

public static void fillImageCatalogue() throws SlickException {
    imageCatalogue.put("PlusButton"         , new Image("res/PlusButton.jpg"));
}

public void initializeGame()  {
    EvoMain.player = new Player((float) 100, (float) 100);
    statScreen.add(EvoMain.player);
    // this line throws an exception in PauseScreen acknowledgeChanges();
}
public Player getPlayer() {
    return player;
}
public void setPlayer(Player player) {
    EvoMain.player = player;
}
@Override
public void update(Observable subject, Object object) {
    if (subject instanceof PauseScreen) {
        switch ((EPauseScreenMessage) object) {
        case EXIT:
            container.exit();
            break;
        case RESUME:
            resumeGame();
            break;
        case START:
            initializeGame();
            resumeGame();
        default:
            break;
        }
    } else
    if (subject instanceof StatScreen) {
        if (object == null) {
            statScreen.setVisible(false);
            statScreen.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
}
}
```

class Player

```
package evo;

import org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.Graphics;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;
import org.newdawn.slick.geom.Vector2f;
import userInterface.StatScreen;

public class Player extends Creature implements Observer, Observable {

private PlayerMessage pMessage = null;

private boolean enemyNearby             = false;

public Player(float x, float y) {
    super(x, y, 10.0, 9);
    setAttackDmg(1.0);
}

@Override
public void render(GameContainer container, Graphics g) throws SlickException {
}

@Override
public void update(EvoMain game) {

}

public void calculateBodyWeight() {

}
public void setDestination(int x, int y) {
    if (x != -1) {
        destinationVector = new Vector2f(x - getPosition().getX(),y - getPosition().getY());
        if (destinationVector.length() == 0.0) { // destination = player position ?
            destinationVector = null; // no need to move then
        }
    } else {
        destinationVector = null; // no destination active -> no vector needed
    }
}

public boolean dealDamage(Creature creature) {
    creature.setInvulnerableTicks(60);
    if (creature.getHp() <= 0) {
        kill(creature);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public void die() {

}
public double getHp() {
    return hp;
}
public boolean hasEnemyNearby() {
    return enemyNearby;
}
public void setEnemyNearby(boolean enemyNearby) {
    this.enemyNearby = enemyNearby;
}
public void acknowledge(EStatMessage message, double value) {
    pMessage = new PlayerMessage(message, value);
    acknowledgeChanges();
}
@Override
public void acknowledgeChanges() {
    for (Observer o : observers) {
        o.update(this, pMessage);
    }
}
public void add(Observer newObs) {
    observers.add(newObs);
}
public void remove(Observer actObs) {
    observers.remove(actObs);
}
@Override
public void update(Observable subject, Object object) {
    if (subject instanceof StatScreen) {

    }
}

@Override
public void kill(Creature creature) {

}
}
```

Interface Observer

```
package evo;

public interface Observer {

void update(Observable subject, Object object);

}
```

Interface Observable

```
package evo;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public interface Observable {

ArrayList<Observer> observers = new ArrayList<Observer>();

public void acknowledgeChanges();
public void add(Observer newObs);
public void remove(Observer actObs);
}
```

Class PauseScreen

```
package userInterface;

import org.newdawn.slick.Color;
import org.newdawn.slick.geom.Rectangle;

import evo.Observable;
import evo.Observer;

public class PauseScreen extends UserInterface implements Observable, Observer {

EPauseScreenMessage message;

public PauseScreen(float x, float y) {
    super(x, y, 300, 400);
    setMainColor(new Color(200, 200, 200));
    setBorderColor(new Color(150, 150, 150));
    TextButton btnStart = new TextButton(getX() + 20, getY() + 20, new Rectangle(getX() + 20, getY() + 20, 200, 75), "Start") {
        @Override
        public void getPressed() {
            if (isEnabled()) {
                message = EPauseScreenMessage.START;
                acknowledgeChanges();
            }
        }
    };
    add(btnStart);
    TextButton btnResume = new TextButton(getX() + 20, getY() + 120, new Rectangle(getX() + 20, getY() + 120, 200, 75), "Resume") {
        @Override
        public void getPressed() {
            if (isEnabled()) {
                message = EPauseScreenMessage.RESUME;
                acknowledgeChanges();
            }
        }
    };
    add(btnResume);
    TextButton btnExit = new TextButton(getX() + 20, getY() + 220, new Rectangle(getX() + 20, getY() + 220, 200, 75), "Exit game") {
        @Override
        public void getPressed() {
            if (isEnabled()) {
                message = EPauseScreenMessage.EXIT;
                acknowledgeChanges();
            }
        }
    };
    btnExit.setTextColor(Color.red);
    add(btnExit);   
}

@Override
public void update(Observable subject, Object object) {

}

@Override
public void acknowledgeChanges() {
    for (Observer obs : observers) {
        obs.update(this, message);
    }
}

@Override
public void add(Observer newObs) {
    observers.add(newObs);
}

@Override
public void remove(Observer actObs) {

}
}
```

Class StatScreen

```
package userInterface;

import org.newdawn.slick.Color;
import org.newdawn.slick.Image;
import org.newdawn.slick.geom.Rectangle;
import evo.Observable;
import evo.Observer;
import evo.Player;
import evo.PlayerMessage;

public class StatScreen extends UserInterface implements Observer, Observable{

String stat = "1";

public StatScreen(float x, float y, Image plusButtonImage) {
    super(x, y, 500, 550);
    mainColor   = new Color(200, 200, 200);
    borderColor = new Color(150, 150, 150);
    TextButton btnClose = new TextButton(getX() + 280, getY() + 460, new Rectangle(getX() + 280, getY() + 460, 200, 75), "Close") {
        @Override
        public void getPressed() {
            if (isEnabled()) {
                stat = "2";
                acknowledgeChanges();
            }
        }
    };
    this.add(btnClose);
}

@Override
public void acknowledgeChanges() {
    for (Observer observer : observers) {
        observer.update(this, stat);
    }
}

@Override
public void add(Observer newObs) {
    observers.add(newObs);
}

@Override
public void remove(Observer actObs) {
    observers.remove(actObs);
}

@Override
public void update(Observable subject, Object object) {
    if (subject instanceof Player) {
        PlayerMessage pM = (PlayerMessage) object;
        switch (pM.getStat()) {
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
public String prepareValue(double value) {
    return (int) value + "." + (int) (value * 10);
}
}
```

Class UserInterface

```
package userInterface;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.newdawn.slick.Color;
import org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.Graphics;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;
import evo.Button;
import evo.EvoObject;

public abstract class UserInterface extends EvoObject {

boolean visible = false;
boolean enabled = false;
int width;
int height;
Color mainColor;
Color borderColor;
ArrayList<Button>   buttons = new ArrayList<Button>();

public UserInterface(float x, float y, int width, int height) {
    super(x, y);
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
}

public void render(GameContainer container, Graphics g) throws SlickException {
    if (visible) {  // render menu if visible
        g.setColor(mainColor);
        g.fillRect(getX(), getY(), this.width, this.height);
        g.setColor(borderColor);
        g.setLineWidth(3);
        g.drawRect(getX(), getY(), this.width, this.height);
        for (Button button : buttons) { // render all buttons
            button.render(container, g);
        }
    }
}

public boolean isVisible() {
    return visible;
}
public void setVisible(boolean visible) {
    this.visible = visible;
}
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return enabled;
}
public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    this.enabled = enabled;
}
public int getWidth() {
    return width;
}
public void setWidth(int width) {
    this.width = width;
}
public int getHeight() {
    return height;
}
public void setHeight(int height) {
    this.height = height;
}
public Color getMainColor() {
    return mainColor;
}
public void setMainColor(Color mainColor) {
    this.mainColor = mainColor;
}
public Color getBorderColor() {
    return borderColor;
}
public void setBorderColor(Color borderColor) {
    this.borderColor = borderColor;
}
public void add(Button button) {
    buttons.add(button);
}
public ArrayList<Button> getButtons() {
    return buttons;
}
}
```

Comment: You need to post your exception stacktrace. Guessing exception point in this wall of text is tiresome and tedious

Comment: I moved it further up, should be in the forth line now.

Comment: Ok, let me see ~

Comment: `StatScreen` constructor `this.add(btnClose); ` -> This is method from super `UserInterface` class?

Comment: Yes it is. It adds the CloseButton to the StatScreen's List of Buttons. My buttons don't implement the observer interface.

Comment: The answer is below. That's a pain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem caused by wrong usage of interface.

```
public interface Observable {

    ArrayList<Observer> observers = new ArrayList<Observer>();
```

You declare a list in `Observable` interface hence it becomes `static`, shared between `PauseScreen` and `StatScreen`

When `START`, your `PauseScreen` notify your observers:

```
case START:
     initializeGame();
     resumeGame();
```

Note that you're iterating `PauseScreen` observers by iterator foreach, in this `case Start` you modifying the underlying list by `add new Player()` to the observable list in `initializeGame` method:

```
public void initializeGame()  {
    EvoMain.player = new Player((float) 100, (float) 100);
    statScreen.add(EvoMain.player);
```

This will throw concurrent modification exception when the `iter.next` is called in `foreach` loop of `PauseScreen.acknowledgeChanges()`.

Solve this problem is easy: remove `ArrayList<Observer> observers` from your `Observable` interface and create in in implementation class (`PauseScreen`, `StatScreen`)

Comment: Wow thanks a lot Mạnh Quyết Nguyễn. I was stuck for two days, now I can finally continue programming. Thank you very much!

Comment: Your code need a refactor, but for now, let rock on~ Cheer!